# SwiftUI - Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0

Tags: swiftui

OK before anymore marks this as duplicate, I have looked at posts similar to this on StackOverFlow and even the Apple forums, and implemented all recommended solutions, yet the problem persists. I've using a LazyVGrid. My code is as follows:

This is my custom scroll view that allows for pagination once the user reaches the end of the scroll:

```
                if !quickSearchViewModel.isLoading && !quickSearchViewModel.search_result.isEmpty {
                    DataFetchingScrollView(.vertical, alignment: .center, onOffsetChange: { (off, height) in
                        offset = off
                        heightMinusOffset = height
                        if heightMinusOffset <= UIScreen.main.bounds.height &&
                            !quickSearchViewModel.search_result.isEmpty {
                            quickSearchViewModel.paginate_searchterm {
                                print("Paginated")
                            } onError: { (error) in
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        createGrid()
                            .id(UUID())
                    }
```

And these are my two functions to create the grid and the view inside the grid:

```
private func createGrid() -> some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(quickSearchViewModel.search_result, id: \.product_uid) { product in
            createProductItemView(product)
                .id(product.product_uid)
            
        }
    }
}
private func createProductItemView(_ product: ProductModel) -> some View {
    ProductItemView(product: product)
        .id(product.product_uid)
}
```

Yes, I know I have spammed the id, but I've added '.id' to all views indivdually and the problem persists. It's as soon as I hit search, the content loads and appears in the grid and thats when my application crashes.

Edit - the `product.product_uid` is an auto-id generated by Firebase. I am literally using this same method in other views, and some work without issues, others may have a little bug.

Comment: I don't see how since I upload to Firebase and each time a new ID is auto-generated. It would make it fairly impossible to do so. I shall look over my database and see if there are two of the same ID's although I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue, it was because I was using `orderBy` when querying data.

Comment: what's wrong with using orderBy ?

i'm facing the same issue now

Comment: @eugene_prg I put it down to the fact I did not use orderBy in the first call however, this may also be down to if you're querying by other fields. I can't give an exact reason why.